# Show the Heaviside step function is continuous in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_\text{lower limit})$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Given $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_\text{lower limit})$ where lower limit
>   topology $\mathcal{T}_\text{lower limit} = \mathcal{T_\mathcal{B}}$ where
>   $\mathcal{B} = \{[a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}, a < b\}$
>
> And $h: (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_\text{lower limit}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}_\text{lower limit})$
>
> $$h(x):=\begin{cases} 1, & x \geq0\\ 0, & x <0 \end{cases}$$
>
> Show $h$ is continuous

Claim: this is trivial

**Attempt:**

> Take some open set $V \subset \mathbb{R}$, if $1 \not
>  \in V $ and  $0 \not \in V $, then $f^{-1}(V) = \varnothing \in
>  \mathcal{T}$
>
> Suppose that $1 \in V$, then $f^{-1}(V) = [0, \infty) \in T$
>
> Otherwise, suppose that $0 \in V$, then  $f^{-1}(V) = (-\infty, 0)$
>
> We can show that $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [a - n, 0)  =
>  (-\infty, 0), a < 0$, hence $(-\infty, 0)$ is open, and $f^{-1}(V) =
>  (-\infty, 0) \in \mathcal{T}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes your proof is correct, with the last case being if both $0,1 \in V$ then $h^{-1}(V) = \mathbb{R} \in \mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Third alternative $0,1$ both in $V$ is trivial but should be mentioned. Also the case $1 \in V$ does not imply inverse image is $[0,\infty)$ since $0$ may also be in $V.$