# How does changing the topology affect a "common" function?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f : (\mathbb R ; \tau) \rightarrow (\mathbb R; \epsilon_1)$, $f(x)=x^2$,

where $\epsilon_1$ denotes the usual topology over $\mathbb R $ and $\tau$ some other topology

what is the difference with this function from elementary calculus

$f : (\mathbb R; \epsilon_1) \rightarrow (\mathbb R; \epsilon_1)$

I mean they both do the same, don't they? like $f(5)=25$ in any of them, then what is the difference?

Comment: Changing the topology doesn't affect the function itself, but can change properties of the function, specifically whether or not it is continuous.

Comment: If you put the [lower limit topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1814031/152568) on $\mathbb R$ then already $f(x)=-x$ becomes discontinuous.